# dollars being sent to me for no reason?

Tags: exchange-rate, price-volatility

I bought 200 ($700 worth) bitcoins in 2012, and I found them last week. Now, my wallet says they are worth $2371959.00 apparently. Is this a scam or do I need to sync my wallet? The computer is pretty old so I'm not sure if it is a virus. Has anyone had this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're trolling or not, but 200 bitcoins is currently worth ~2,357,000$. ( Which seems to pretty aligned with the number you are giving.)

There's no virus/scam or bug, the price simply increased. Congratulations.

I'd advise you to make a backup of the private key of the adress you're currently storing the 200 bitcoins on, and either memorize it, or hide it, in case your old PC / ( the harddrive of your old pc) breaks.

Or even better, buy a hardware wallet (such as a trezor or Ledger Nano S) Or a secure new PC/Laptop, and store the bitcoins on there.

Comment: thanks, is coinbase a good place to sell?

Comment: Not necessarily "good", ( in terms of fees), but it is a safe and secure place to sell your bitcoins, yes.

Comment: By transferring funds from Coinbase to the "sister site" GDAX, and by using a "limit" order you can avoid pretty much all the fees: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JNH3AFRatrM Or you could send the BTC to GDAX directly. (Note that if the OP truly has 200 BTC to sell it may take a long time to withdraw the funds… I've never had to take that into consideration ;-)